# memcache installation issue when calling phpize

Tags: php, memcached

I have downloaded the latest version of memcache from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package-stats.php?pid=294&rid=&cid=3). After I run commands that below..

```
tar xvf memcache-3.0.8.tgz
cd memcache-3.0.8
/usr/local/php/bin/phpize
```

the latest line is the where my problem starting. Hash says *there is no folder or file like this*.

Comment: What is the output when you run `which phpize`?

Comment: oops, can't understand?

Comment: Type in the following into your terminal and paste the output here: `which phpize`

Comment: @MSost there is no output..

Comment: You may need to install php5-dev before you can use phpize. `sudo apt-get install php5-dev`

Comment: @AndrewRyno thanks that solve my problem. Also I have found phpize directory with which phpize. Now memcache works.. :)